# jQuery on PC returns element ID, on Android returns 'undefined'. Why?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, undefined

I'm working with *jQuery* right now and the problem is: on **PC** I am able to change the .html() content of the button but on **Android** device I can't. So I decided to debug it by checking whether the jQuery gets the id attribute of the target element.

The simplified html looks like that:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <button id='button1'>Test </button>
      <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Now the jQuery part:

```
$(document).on("click", "ul > li > ul > li" , function(){
        alert($(this).parent().prev('button').attr("id"));
});
```

What happens:
On a **PC** I get the button id attribute in the alert.

On **Android** I get 'undefined' in the alert.

What is causing this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm running it directly from chrome browser on the android device.

Comment: Did you use jQuery min file ?

Comment: <script src="[https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js)"></script>
It's not min I believe.

Comment: try load instead script that is jquerty mobile. Read more here : https://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem, and it is actually not a problem at all. It's just a thing I didn't know. I didn't know it was specific to the BootStrap framework. The thing is, on mobile devices it appears to add an additional element with **.dropdown-backdrop** class when adding these `<ul> <li>` based drop down menus. I should've mentioned that I was using bootstrap in the first place.